# Playing in a soccer club

Tags: halal-haram, sports

Can I play for a soccer club that is very near my home, as I can't go any further? But this club is called Saint Paul, and the soccer club is kind of religious to Christianity?

Comment: `the soccer club is kind of religious to Christianity` can you elaborate more on that? I know many Christian organization (like the YMCA for example) that doesn't really have anything to do with forcing people to study certain things.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't stray off the path, there should be no problem with it. It's a soccer club, so I doubt that they will force you to go to church on Sundays. If you are worried about it, find another club.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, working is not considered as a negative practice, unless in some items such as:

- The act would create the field of sins or immorality …
- This act makes the Moslems weaker
- Its benefits go for Kafir-al-Harbi

Of course it could be advised not to live in non-Islamic countries if there is no necessity …

**Accordingly, there is no matter if you work there if the above-mentioned items are not related to that.**

---

References:

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa51697)

[http://ahkam.tebyan.net](http://ahkam.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=290410)